# Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject

Tags: parse-platform

I am getting below error after updating to parse's latest release.

```
Result: Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject
at n.value (Parse.js:12:4222)
at n (Parse.js:14:607)
at Parse.js:14:374
at Array.map (native)
at n (Parse.js:14:351)
at Object.r.default (Parse.js:14:1071)
at Object.b._encode (Parse.js:11:15607)
at Object.success (<anonymous>:156:42)
at e.rQuery.find.success (main.js:279:22)
at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:12:27827)
```

for below code

```
rQuery.equalTo("rNumber", r2Number);
    rQuery.descending("rDateTime");
    rQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
        results = editListForSectionHeader(results);
        response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // on error, log it
        console.log(error.message);
        response.success([]);
    }

function editListForSectionHeader(results){
var previousDate = '';
var formatedResults = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
  var object = results[i];
  if(previousDate != object.get('rDate')){
    var headerRow = new R();
    headerRow.set("rDate", object.get('rDate'));
    headerRow.set("rowType", "HEADER_ROW");
    formatedResults.push(headerRow);
    object.set("rowType", "DATA_ROW");
    formatedResults.push(object);
    previousDate = object.get('rDate');
    headerRow.dirty = function() { return false; };
    object.dirty = function() { return false; };
  }else{
    object.set("rowType", "DATA_ROW");
    object.dirty = function() { return false; };
    formatedResults.push(object);
  }
}
return formatedResults;
}
```

Basically I am getting some data with query, formatting the result array, setting dirty properties to false and returning. It use to work but it stopped with the new version.

Comment: The question title is the correct answer:  the essential parts of a pointer is the class and the object ID.  Unsaved objects have no ID, so it is impossible to create a pointer using them.  I can't imagine how this worked before, except that parse.com didn't provided the error check.  Can you post what you're trying to do with the pointer?  Someone can help you get that done with just the new object (probably just by using the new object instead of the pointer).

Comment: I am not able to get the complete gist of what you are saying.  Just to be clear `response.success(results);` this line is the one throwing this error. Basically I have my results and then `editListForSectionHeader ` method modifies results array for header and section rows and then I send it to client.

Comment: how can I then send a modified result array without saving the changes to it ?